# Count number of ';' in column

Tags: linux, awk

I use the following command to count number of `;` in a first line in a file:

```
awk -F';' '(NR==1){print NF;}' $filename
```

I would like to do same with all lines in the same file. That is to say, count number of `;` on all line in file.

What I have :

```
$ awk -F';' '(NR==1){print NF;}' $filename
11
```

What I would like to have :

```
11
11
11
11
11
11
```

Comment: I'm trying to improve post to say Hello community but I can't update it. Sorry to all :)

Comment: Have you tried removing the part that selects the first line so it applies to all lines?

Comment: @MarkSetchell although that will count one `;` more for each line AFAICT?

Comment: You should generally surround accesses to shell variables with double quotes, like this `"$filename"` otherwise your scripts will fail miserably when you use a file with spaces in its name.

Comment: @Jir Yes, indeed, I was coming to that part next but didn't want to confuse a new user with another issue all in one go... and he also seems happy enough with a *"one out error"* in his original post.

Comment: Stack Overflow actively discourages hello, thanks, etc. Don't apologize for not putting in content we would remove anyway.

Comment: I'm confused by your last sentence; some sample input and desired output would help to clarify things. Can you [edit] your question to add a few lines of input and the output that you would expect?

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. I have a solution with Ravinger post.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question, I updated it to improve the formatting. It would be good if you also included the input which produces that output.

Comment: @tripleee removing contents are not good when user is already ready to provide informations expected, give people time to get accustomed with this community rather to jump into bandwagon of closing or removing questions like this. This kind of behaviour only discourage people not to ask for a help when needed most.

Comment: @Skynet Huh? Closing as unclear is quite different from removing a post. Closing is in fact a meaningful signal to give the OP an opportunity to clarify their problem, and to readers that the post is not sufficiently well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight forward method to count `;` per line should be:

```
awk '{print gsub(/;/,"&")}' Input_file
```

To remove empty lines try:

```
awk 'NF{print gsub(/;/,"&")}' Input_file
```

To do this in OP's way reduce 1 from value of `NF`:

```
awk -F';' '{print (NF-1)}' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk -F';' 'NF{print (NF-1)}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinger. It is what I looked for. But why I have a 0 number of a last colomn ?

Comment: @Ops it sounds like you have an empty line at the end of your file, so `gsub` returns `0` because it did 0 replacements. But it also sounds like you are confusing the word "column" with "line". As I mentioned in the comments above, you should edit your question to add some example input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns a number one more than the number of semicolons; `NF` is the number of fields you get from splitting on a semicolon (so for example, if there is one semicolon, the line is split in two).

If you want to add this number from each line, that's easy;

```sh
awk -F ';' '{ sum += NF-1 } END { print sum }' "$filename"
```

If the number of fields is consistent, you could also just count the number of lines and multiply;

```sh
awk -F ':' 'END { print NR * (NF-1) }' "$filename"
```

But that's obviously wrong if you can't guarantee that all lines contain exactly the same number of fields.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you can solve your problem with the following:

```
awk -F';' '{if (NF) {a += NF-1;}} END {print a}' test.txt
```

You want to keep a running count of all the occurrences made (variable `a`).

As `NF` will return the number of fields, which is one more than the number of separators, you'll need to subtract 1 for each line. This is the `NF-1` part.

However, you don't want to count "-1" for the lines in which there is no separator at all. To skip those you need the `if (NF)` part.

Here's a (perhaps contrived) example:

```
$ cat test.txt 
;;
; ; ; ;;
; asd ;;a 
a ; ;

$ awk -F';' '{if (NF) {a += NF-1;}} END {print a}' test.txt
12
```

Notice the empty line at the end (to test against the "no separator" case).

Answer (score 1):

A different approach using `tr` and `wc`:

```
$ tr -cd ';' < file | wc -c
42
```